# update field from dropdown list PHP

Tags: php

When i update the field in textbox the code retrieve the data from database and update it fine. but when I change it to dropdownlist it doesn't retrieve data and doesn't update them what is the problem.

```php
<form>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row['P_id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['P_id'] ?>">

    <!-- Select parking type -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="type">Parking Type</label>

      <?php $connect=m ysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "root", "pms"); $dbQuery="SELECT * FROM parking_type" ; $dbResult=m ysqli_query($connect,$dbQuery); echo '<select id="typ-'.$row[ 'P_id']. '">'; while($rw=m ysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)) { echo
      '<option value="'.$rw[0]. '" > '.$rw[1]. ' </option>'; } echo "</select>"; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Edit parking code -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pc">Parking Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pno-<?php echo $row['P_id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['P_code'] ?>">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="updateData(<?php echo $row['P_id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That semicolon `;` after your `while` is tricking you.

Comment: where is your attribute name for select element

Comment: It select the data from database but it must show the value that i want to update.

Comment: remove `;` from while as Tolios suggest already

Comment: there are 2 attribute which  are t_id and type

Comment: $row in select tag is also wrong. as you are fetching data in net line

Comment: I removed it .. same problem

Comment: why $row is wrong what shall I write instad

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @raiya, where is your `name` attribute. How do you update it by php or you are using jQuery

Comment: no but the selected data is not appear in the fields.

Comment: $P_id = $_POST['P_id'];
 $type = $_POST['typ'];
 $p_no = $_POST['pno'];
 
 $stmt = $db->prepare("update parking_details set t_id=?, P_code=? where P_id=?");
 $stmt->bindParam(1,$type);
 $stmt->bindParam(2,$p_no);
 $stmt->bindParam(3,$P_id);

Comment: i use function to update it work fine becouse when i change the dropdown to textbox the data updated

Comment: ok, stop! do you send your form values via js? ok, i see it, let me look one minutes.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have changed your code, please look here and try it:

your form code:

```
<form id="jsForm" action="pserver.php" type="POST">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="P_id" value="<?php echo $row['P_id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">
    <!-- Select parking type -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="<?php echo 'typ-'.$row[ 'P_id']; ?>">Parking Type</label>
      <?php 
      $connect = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "root", "pms"); 
      $dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM parking_type" ; 
      $dbResult = mysqli_query($connect,$dbQuery); 
      echo '<select name="typ-'.$row[ 'P_id']. '">'; 
      while($rw = msqli_fetch_array($dbResult)) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$rw[0]. '" > '.$rw[1]. ' </option>'; 
      } 
      echo "</select>";       

      ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Edit parking code -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pno-<?php echo $row['P_id']; ?>">Parking Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pno-<?php echo $row['P_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['P_code']; ?>">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>

//hang on event of form with id=myform
    $("form#jsForm").on('submit', function(e) {

        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();

        //get the url of the form
        var url = $(this).attr('action');

        //get form values
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        //do your own request an handle the results
        $.ajax({
                url: 'pserver.php', // or set "url" var, if form action defined
                type: 'POST',
                //dataType: 'json',
                data: values,
                success: function(resp) {
                    //alert(resp);
                    viewData();
                }
        });

    });

</script>
```

a part of your php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action'], $_POST['P_id']) && $_POST['action'] == "edit" && !empty($_POST['P_id'])) {

$P_id = $_POST['P_id'];
$type = isset($_POST["typ-$P_id"]) ? $_POST["typ-$P_id"] : false;
$p_no = isset($_POST["pno-$P_id"]) ? $_POST["pno-$P_id"] : false;

    if($type && $p_no) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("update parking_details set t_id=?, P_code=? where P_id=?");
  $stmt->bindParam(1,$type); // you can add pdo validation here (read more http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
  $stmt->bindParam(2,$p_no); // and here
  $stmt->bindParam(3,$P_id); // and here
  $stmt->execute();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very match it update fine and it retrive all other fields data but remains the value of dropdown list it always show the first. i must show the value of that record from database

Comment: sorry but where can i post my full code ? in comment??

Comment: you can post your code here https://jsfiddle.net, save it and post link here in comment.

Comment: i post it in new answer